# How to set the max date of being today for date_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have where a person can choose date of birth:

```
= form.date_select :date_of_birth, start_year: Date.current.year, end_year: Date.current.year - 333
```

I want it to have the maximum date of today. **The max day must be equal to today and max month. Not only year.**

I've tried "min: Date.today" and "max: Date.today" and it didn't work out.

How can I do that?

Comment: `date_select` is not able to limit the range. For that try some js date picker/write own

Answer (score 2):

Ok, based on the negative points I got on my previous answer, let me explain this a bit more. The Rails datepicker renders three selects, one for day, one for month and one for year. Since this is "fixed" there's no option to reduce the amount of days or months. This would not allow you to select a valid date anymore. The only thing you can change is the range of years. You already did that in your sample code.

Now, back to your use case. You'd like to prevent someone inputing a date in the future? Sure. You've got three options:

1. Only validate this server side, through a model validation and
   present the user back with the error message: "birth date should be
   in the past". Always do this!!

The following are nice-to-haves to add to 1:

2. Capture form submission through JS, check the submitted date and
   show error in case the date is invalid
3. Change the way you display the date through some kind of
   Datepicker plugin. jQuery UI has a few nice one:
   https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. This one allows you to better
   configure allowed dates, since it is programmed client-side

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even with client-side smart UI, a server-side check is a must-have.

Comment: One could probably do away with _just_ the server-side check. Just emit dynamic validation error: `"date: cannot be greater than #{Date.today}"`. Not the best UX, but takes two minutes to implement.

Comment: @Jerry Your question **has** been answered. If you feel that the answer is unsatisfactory, could you provide some feedback that's a little more constructive than "re-read my question"?

Comment: @Jerry Are you unsure how to implement validations? Or how to implement a JS datepicker? Or maybe the thing you're looking for is just a chunk of code to blindly copy+paste?

Answer (score -2):

Don't bother about dates in the future yet. Just ignore such bad entries for now. Best to add a validation to the model that checks whether the submitted `date < Date.today`. If you do wish to have front-end / client-side validation, look for a JS / jQuery datepicker. These are more easy to configure and support direct inline error messages.

Comment: *"If you do wish to have front-end / client-side validation, look for a JS / jQuery datepicker."* -- **This** part of your answer is on the right lines. But just saying that "the answer is to not bother" isn't much help!

Comment: I don't think the standard Rails date picker supports setting max month and/or date, since that would be impossible as it is rendered back-end. But I;ll adapt the answer.